# Update the dash datatable with new rows through callback

Tags: python, sql, plotly-dash

I wish to have an updated dashtable from the sql query that is used in the callback, it would be updated every few seconds. However, there's error getting the new rows.
Been struck for some time now
Any help would be nice
Error:
Callback error updating raw_data.data

Code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_table
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly
import pyodbc

def connectSQLServer(driver, server, db):
    connSQLServer = pyodbc.connect(
        r'DRIVER={' + driver + '};'
        r'SERVER=' + server + ';'
        r'DATABASE=' + db + ';'
        r'Trusted_Connection=yes;',
        autocommit=True
    )
    return connSQLServer

sql_conn = connectSQLServer(
    'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server', 'DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS', 'display')
cursor = sql_conn.cursor()
d = {'x': [], 'y': [], 'z': [], 'a': []}
sql = 'select * from dbo.data2'
cursor.execute(sql)
myresult = cursor.fetchall()
# d = { 'x': [], 'y': [] }
for x in myresult:
    d['x'].append(x[0])
    d['y'].append(x[1])
    d['z'].append(x[2])
    d['a'].append(x[3])
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([dash_table.DataTable(id='raw_data',

                                            columns = [{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns],
                                            data = df.to_dict("rows"),
                                            ),
                       dcc.Interval(id='interval_component',
                                    interval=1000,
                                    n_intervals=0
                                    )
                       ])
d = {'x': [], 'y': [], 'z': [], 'a': []}

@app.callback(Output('raw_data', 'data'), [Input('interval_component', 'n_intervals')])
def update_table(n_intervals):
    sql_conn = connectSQLServer(
        'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server', 'DESKTOP\SQL', 'display')
    cursor = sql_conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM dbo.data2")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for x in rows:
        d['x'].append(x[0])
        d['y'].append(x[1])
        d['z'].append(x[2])
        d['a'].append(x[3])
    df = pd.Dataframe(d)
    return df
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(port=7000, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output data `df` must be in json format. Change to `return df.to_json("records")`

Also, there's no need to perform your sql query twice. I'd say instantiate your datatable with empty data. Your callback will fire on instantiation of `dcc.Interval` since you're assigning `n_intervals=0`. All your querying + transformations can take place in the callback.